# Angular js - Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibmodalProvider <- $uibmodal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to Angular and trying to use $uibmodal but getting the below error while running: 
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibmodalProvider <- $uibmodal

I am using the below versions: 
Angular version: 1.5.11 
Angular Bootstrap version: 2.5.0.

I think there is some compatibility issue between the versions.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you injected the UI-bootstrap module (`'ui.bootstrap'`) into your app's root module?

Comment: Added $uibmodal in dependancy injection?

Comment: I have injected 'ui.bootstrap' into the app's root module: var myApp= angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap',]

Comment: Added the $uibmodal in dependancy injection, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at error it seems like you made typo in dependency name, it should be `$uibModal` instead of `$uibmodal`